# How many times can you double?

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics

You are allowed to select $n$ positive real numbers.

Then, you have to select a sequence of nonempty subsets of these numbers, such that the sum of each subset is more than twice the sum of the previous subset.

That is, at each day $t\geq 1$, you should select a subset $S_t$ such that $\sum S_t > 2 \sum S_{t-1}$ for all $t\geq 2$.

What is the longest sequence you can select?

A sequence of length $n$ is obviously possible, if we select the initial numbers e.g. to be a geometric sequence of ratio larger than 2. Then, each day we pick a subset that contains the next largest element. But with this selection, we cannot get a sequence longer than $n$.

Is there a difference selection of the initial numbers, with which it is possible to get a sequence longer than $n$?

In particular, is it possible to have a sequence of length exponential in $n$?

Comment: Please see [this article on MathSE protocol](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236).
As onerous as the article may appear to you, it provides a defense mechanism against the MathSE forum being used as a *do my homework* forum.  In particular, please see the **Edit-Tools** section of the article, and the portion of the article that discusses *showing work*.  It is **irrelevant** whether the problem is homework.  What counts is whether the protocol is observed.

Comment: Hint: $\{1,3,7,15,...\}.$

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: After 10 years you should know how to ask a good question.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork A sequence of length $n$ is easy, but the number of subsets is $2^n$, so I thought maybe  it is possible to get a sequence of length exponential in $n$. But so far I could not generate such a sequence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The longest possible sequence is $n$.
*Proof*: if $\sum S_t > 2 \sum S_{t-1}$ for all $t\geq 2$, then
$$\sum S_t > \sum S_{t-1} + \sum S_{t-2} + \cdots  + \sum S_1$$
for all $t\geq 2$.

This means that the set $S_t$ must contain at least one new item, that is not contained in any of the sets $S_{t-1},\ldots,S_1$. Therefore, at most $n$ sets are possible.